# WIn64 memory mapped files and locking pages

Tags: c++, windows, performance, memory-management, 64-bit

I need to grab large amounts (4-8Gb) of data in realtime - without dropping any data.

The old system could just about keep up with writing the data to a striped RAID array but the data has got bigger, faster than the disk have got faster (!)  So I don't have time to access the disk.
The new plan is to switch to Win64, install LOTS of ram, stuff the incoming data into a buffer and then write it all at the end.

So I'm looking for:
A windows API that limits new[] to physical memory and locks pages into physical ram, or I just disable the pagefile.

Or I use memory mapped files and force a sync at the end when I close the file. Is there a memory mapped file flag that prevents a write behind until I am ready?

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1039017/404501

Comment: @Markus - there are a lot of problems with just 'use virtuallock' was hoping some people had more opinions.

Comment: I think the general problem boils down to, 'not-designed-for-this'. You can allocate non-paged-pool memory in kernel mode, to prevent it from being swapped out. On the other hand, maybe mapping would help. Memory will only be swapped to disc if the system cannot hold more disc cache. This should not happen, until memory for the disc cache runs low.

Comment: @MartinBeckett I would just like to point you to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , because if you are going to be operating on very large, contiguous memory block it is best to minimize the overhead this would incur to the TLB if you are using small pages, so in this case it would make sense to use large-pages

Comment: @Christopher - I know I know! Windows is not really even upto the job of capturing the data(200Mb/s) in the first place, then somebody added a "can we save all the data for quality control?" requirement. ps The trouble is I can't control when the system decides to commit memory mapped files.

Comment: @LordDoskias - the trouble is the drives can't keep up with the data stream it's not just overhead. I need to store an entire run in ram and then dump it later 'off line'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you'll have to do is overload operator new and allocate and lock that memory yourself.

1. Call [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to allocate your chunk of memory.
2. Call [VirtualLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to lock those pages to physical RAM. Note that it can sometimes be difficult to convince windows to do this, but will usually work if you have way more than enough RAM and you have set the process working set size appropriately using [SetProcessWorkingSetSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note the special [PROCESS_SET_QUOTA permission the user account your process is running under will need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using plain old `VirtualAlloc` and locking the pages yourself, you could call VirtualAlloc with the `MEM_LARGE_PAGES` parameter. You need to set some settings beforehand though: [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Large pages are by default non pageable and obviously more efficient wrt overhead. Beware that allocation times for large pages can be problematic on fragmented heaps. You may want to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/28/10121300.aspx) as well.

Comment: It's generally hard to get a contiguous block of 4-8Gb on Windows so the buffering is designed to handle lists of 1Mb chunks. It would be nice to be able to lock all of it rather than each block on it's own though

Comment: @MartinBeckett Can you allocate the memory at startup of the application? The fragmentation on the heap should be low at that point in time and the calls succeed. The design goal for that API were large, single purpose machines so there are limitations, but I could imagine it to fit to your goal. Locking the memory yourself afterwards will have pretty much the same and additional problems though so I fear it's the best (least worse) option.

Comment: that was the plan, the requirement is to be able to save data if a condition occurs so no delay. Can you always get a large page if the machine has been running for a while and other processes have fraged the memory?

Comment: @Martin No you can't. If the heap has become fragmented windows may not be able to satisfy the demand. But that's a very basic limitation you won't be able to overcome on Windows (or any os that doesn't just kill other processes in that situation) regardless of which API you use. Also allocating such large pages does take a lot of time if the heap is fragmented even if the OS can satisfy it finally (which may mean shuffling mbs of data around, paging other stuff out - you get the idea). Which makes it rather useless if you have to do it under time constraints.

Comment: that was the reason for slicing the store into a vector of 1Mb blocks, but then you have to call virtuallock() on each - I was hoping for an easier soln. I think I will test the memory mapped file and see if it actually commits while there is ram

Answer (score 0):

One quick way would be to disable the system paging file system wide. You can create a special heap for your data, that uses physical memory only, but the new/delete stuff that takes care of memory management for small bits of data usually use the process heap. Use the HeapCreate() function from the win api. Now you must get new/delete to use that heap.

Comment: I can use any memory allocator and I work on an array of 1Mb blocks allocated at the start so there is no requirement for the whole buffer to be contiguous. Is there anything in HeapCreate() that guarantees it won't page? I thought it just restricted it to a single process?

Comment: If you allocate only large (1 MB +) blocks, use HeapAlloc() and HeapReAlloc() from the winapi. If you still need to use new/delete and rely on the use of physical memory exclusively, you must post a another question how to do this. It probably can be found in the manual of the STD-RTL of your compiler vendor.

Comment: The process heap is created by windows, before the entry point of your programme. The things you want should be configurable in the EXE - file. Maybe there's a linker option to get it done.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any difference with heapalloc/new/malloc and virtuallock. But there doesn't seem to be a way of ensuring the private heapcreate will be in physical ram before locking it

Comment: Unless you've given the user the "lock physical memory" privilege, you won't be able to `VirtualLock` very much memory. `HeapCreate` always creates a pageable heap. You have to lock it afterwards; and locking is what forces it into physical memory.